# How can I toggle sort order with a button on bootstrap page without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5, dot.js

I am building a template for an existing app, and want to include a button to change the sort order of elements displayed on a web page. The page uses Bootstrap 5.3 for styling, so I already have jQuery and other features of Bootstrap available.

I simply want a button that reverses the order of the array allowing toggling the sort order, and reflects this on the page without reloading it.

Here is the HTML for some entries:

```html
<button type="button" onClick="reverseEntries();">Reverse order of entries</button>
<div id="entries">
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Entry 0</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Entry 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Entry 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

The elements I want to sort are available from a JavaScript object named `entries` that is already populated when the page loads. For simplicity sake, you can treat it as an array like this:

```js
entries = [
   'Entry 0',
   'Entry 1',
   'Entry 2'
]
```

The template engine is [dot.js](https://olado.github.io/doT/), and iterates through the array and writes each div client side - i.e. each array member value is written between the h2 tags.

Here is the template, that builds the html snippet.

```
<div id="entries">
  {{~ entries:entry:index}} <!-- iterates through the entries array -->
  <div class="card">
    <h2>{{=entry}}</h2>
  </div>
  {{~}} <!-- end of iteration block -->
</div>
```

I can use `entries.reverse()` to reverse the order of the array, but I'm not sure how to redo the page after reversing the array.

Here is the function so far:

```js
function reverseEntries(){
  entries = entries.reverse(); // this successfully reverses the array
  // how can I update the page so the entries appear in the new order of the array.
}
```

I could achieve the same output by just reloading the page with a different query, but since all the data is already in JavaScript I'd prefer to do it client side.

Comment: An id that starts with a number will most likely cause issues in JS. Despite that, a data-attribute would be more appropriate. What have you tried to sort? Sorting an array should not be really difficult...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? You haven't shared any JS code so far

Comment: I removed the ID attributes as they were misleading. I just want to reverse the order in the array and have the page reflect that.

Comment: you can create two variable one for original array and also assign same array  in 2nd variable. When you need to reverse the array you can use 2nd array variable and your original array will safe.

Comment: How does your existing code convert your variable `entries` into the HTML?  You should be able to re-call that function after .reverse().  You may need to `.empty()` the container first.

Comment: Note: if your HTML is a bunch of `div` then you could also do this with `flex` css by changing the classname on the container and appropriate css.

Comment: @freedomn-m the template engine iterates through the array and writes each div.

Comment: Are you using dot.js server side?  If not, can you call it from within your `reverseEntries()` function?

Comment: `entries = entries.reverse()` - what does that do? I don't see where you've defined that variable after all

Comment: Client side in the browser. Thanks for suggestions - I'm getting somewhere.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Where's the code that initializes `entries`?

Comment: `entries` is created by PHP server side when the page is loaded. Would it help to see a sample?

Comment: That would help, especially as you haven't shared how that array is written to the markup in the first place, and how you plan to update that

Comment: Hi @dunxd, you can use the same function `entries = entries.reverse()` to toggle the order of the array. It will act as a toggle functionality to change the order in reverse once executed and will change to original order when called again. I hope this will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @JigneshRaval - I understand that.  What I am struggling with is how to update the rendered page once the order of the array is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some suggestions and probing questions in the comments, I figured out what I needed to do using jQuery to refresh the HTML in my template.

Key was understanding how doT.js writes the page.

After reversing the array, I needed to recompile the relevant template incorporating the data, then use jQuery to rewrite the HTML in the relevant container.

```js
function reverseEntriesOrder() {
  var template = doT.template("entries.html"); // Loads the template text into doT
  var resultHTML = template(entries.reverse()); // applies the changed data to the template
  $('#main').html(resultHTML); // updates the HTML in the main DIV with the new value
}
```

Now I can call `reverseEntriesOrder()` from an onClick event and the order of the items will be updated.

Comment: Great job @dunxd. Thanks for sharing the root cause and the solution. Q :- Just want to ask that is doT.js better then Handlebars.js?

Comment: I don't have experience with handlebars.js so can't really answer that question. It looks to have similar features, so I guess it would come down to performance. The app I am templating for has a server side implementation of doT written in PHP by the original developer which is not feature complete. The current developer is considering switching to twig which has both js and PHP implementations.